# simple encryption scheme turns out to be “somewhat homomorphic”

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

In the paper [Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616) in the introduction:

How do I calculate $r$ and $q$ of this equation in the picture?

$r \approx 2^{\sqrt{\eta}}$ and $q \approx 2^{\eta^3}$

what is the meaning of symbol like $\eta$ in the picture?

$p\in [2^{\eta-1},2^\eta)$

and how calculate it?

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE. Please edit your question and add a link to the paper you're quoting.

Comment: It's just the key size, which is a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

η is the bit-length of the secret key (which is the hidden approximate-gcd of all the public-key
integers),

SO u can calculate given functions and P should be the key that will be used and it should be between [2^η−1,2^η)

Hope this answers your question